# How to give Forget password option for a password encrypted file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, encryption

I have created a utility that encrypts a file (.txt, .dox, so on...). The time of file encryption the utility asks for a password from user.

**Problem**

Suppose user have created 1000 encrypted files with diffrent passwords and forgets his password of some file. How will he recover it?

**My thoughts**

I should log each password(encrypted) some where and by the name and size of file we can find the password of the file which can be provided to the user but here are some catch:

1. There can be many files with the same name and size
2. User can rename the file so here we will be help less
3. if we try to find the password by only size then there can be many files with same size then it will not be a good way to provide user the exact password.

I also thought to send the whole password log to user on his regeister email but then I found this [LINK](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure) and changed my thought.

**Request**

What will be the best way to provide user the exact password of the encrypted file?

Comment: If you can provide the password back to the user, what is the point of asking to create one?

Comment: How are you encrypting the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash function such as SHA-256 to identify the files. Common Crypto on an iPhone6s will process 1MB in ~ 2.3msec.

You need to carefully consider how an attacker might use the password recovery feature to optain the file's contents.

```
+ (NSData *)doSha256:(NSData *)dataIn {
    NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA256( dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length, macOut.mutableBytes);

    return macOut;
}
```

Comment: sir, could you please elaborate how can I use SHA-256 to identify a file. Also, will it work on the files as big as 500mb to 1gb (Just confirming if there is a size limit). I am a newbie, please..please please be a little lenient towards me.

Comment: SHA is a hash function (Secure Hash Algorithm). You use it by  having it process all the bytes in a file and produce a 32-byte hash. The same hash is produced every time and the chances of two different files having the same hash is: never. There is no size limit, there is a time cost, as in the answer that the speed is about 450 MB/sec in an iPhone5S.